# How to define application specific error code in Swagger

Tags: swagger

I'd like to define the possible application error code, not HTTP status code, for example:

In the returned JSON

```
{
   code: 2000,
   message: "create success"

} // or

{
   code: 2001
   message: "user already exists"
}
```

....

I know you can define a schema for this structure, but schema is not enough here, since I need to define possible code and message.

Is it possible? If so, how to do it in Swagger?